# How to validate forms on client-side with Flask?

Tags: ajax, flask

I am trying to write a simple Flask API that reads fields `name` , `email` , `phone` , `message` with POST, validates them , and returns true or false depending on the output of the validation - to the following JS script. How can I do that?

```
@app.route('/email' , methods = ['POST'])
def email():
    name = request.form["name"]
    phone = request.form["phone"]
    email = request.form["email"]
    message = request.form["message"]
    return json.dumps({'status' : 'OK' , 'name' : name , 'phone' : phone , 'email' : email , 'message' : message});
```

.

```
$(function() {

    $("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
            // additional error messages or events
        },
        submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
            // event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
            // get values from FORM
            var name = $("input#name").val();
            var email = $("input#email").val();
            var phone = $("input#phone").val();
            var message = $("textarea#message").val();
            var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
            // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
            if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
                firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: "/email",
                data: $('form').serialize(),
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                success: function() {
                    // Success message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append('</div>');

                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
                error: function() {
                    // Fail message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
            })
        },
        filter: function() {
            return $(this).is(":visible");
        },
    });

    $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab("show");
    });
});


/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$('#name').focus(function() {
    $('#success').html('');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Validation data on client side is generally bad idea. Maybe some kind of pre-validation is OK, but in any case, final decision should be taken on the server side.

For server-side validation for form you can check [WTForms](https://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) library, that contains some classes of pre-defined validators.

Comment: To accomplish what the question is asking, could we possibly create a WTForms object from the JSON that gets posted, check whether the WTForms object will validate, and return `true` or `false` as JSON?

Comment: @KylePittman I think this is possible, but I'm not sure it is the correct way for managing data. But even in this case validationwill beperformed on the server-side, not client side, as it was asked.

Comment: Good point, I had assumed that 'client-side validation" in this case meant to give the user feedback before the form was actually submitted. But that may not be the case.

Comment: @wanderlust Is validation performed server-side in WTF validators? Any reference for that?

Comment: @DrimadesBoy WTF is a library that runs under Flask. Flask runs on the server-side. Therefore, yes, WTF-validators are performed on the server-side.

Comment: @wanderlust I get it. However, it looks like some of the validators work client-side, e.g. the DataRequired validator.